# how to get back a variable from mainwindow to a pop up?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a game for a school project in qt. I want to get back an information from a variable of the main Windows into a pop up, how can do ?

I have my pop up created but that's all

Comment: If your code that creates the popup is in your main-window class (or has access to your main-window class) you could pass in the information that the pop-up will need to the pop-up class's constructor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can figure that when the popup will be instantiated, the main window infos will be correct and won't change when needed in the popup, you can make the definition of constructor of the popup including those infos (you'll need to have a custom "popup" class, let's say MyDialog):

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDialog(double mainWindowSuperValue = 0., QWidget *parent = nullptr);
[...]
};
```

2. If you know that the value can change, but during the few moment when the popup will be shown, it won't change, you can define your custom 'show' function :

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
[...]
public slots:
    void showPopup(double mainWindowSuperValue = 0.);
[...]
};


MyDialog::showPopup(double mainWindowSuperValue)
{
    // do whatever you need with mainWindowSuperValue
    show();
}
```

3. If you need to get the info at a specific time, because the main window infos can change while the pop up is open (whatever the reason), you can use the parent() function and cast it to MyMainWindow :

```
    auto theParent = qobject_cast<MyMainWindow*>(this->parent());
    if(theParent)
    {
        // do whatever you need with theParent->m_mySuperValue
    }
```

(you can also use this method in the first case (1.) in the constructor with `parent` argument instead of parent())